# How can I do this in a faster way?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have a script that imports CSV files. What ends up in my database is, among other things, a list of customers and a list of addresses. I have a table called `customer` and another called `address`, where `address` has a `customer_id`.

One thing that's important to me is not to have any duplicate rows. Therefore, each time I import an address, I do something like this:

```
$address = new Address();
$address->setLine_1($line_1);
$address->setZip($zip);
$address->setCountry($usa);
$address->setCity($city);
$address->setState($state);
$address = Doctrine::getTable('Address')->findOrCreate($address);
$address->save();
```

What `findOrCreate()` does, as you can probably guess, is find a matching address record if it exists, otherwise just return a new `Address` object. Here is the code:

```
  public function findOrCreate($address)
  {
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
      ->select('a.*')
      ->from('Address a')
      ->where('a.line_1 = ?', $address->getLine_1())
      ->andWhere('a.line_2 = ?', $address->getLine_2())
      ->andWhere('a.country_id = ?', $address->getCountryId())
      ->andWhere('a.city = ?', $address->getCity())
      ->andWhere('a.state_id = ?', $address->getStateId())
      ->andWhere('a.zip = ?', $address->getZip());

    $existing_address = $q->fetchOne();

    if ($existing_address)
    {
      return $existing_address;
    }
    else
    {
      return $address;
    }
  }
```

The problem with doing this is that it's slow. To save each row in the CSV file (which translates into several `INSERT` statements on different tables), it takes about a quarter second. I'd like to get it as close to "instantaneous" as possible because I sometimes have over 50,000 rows in my CSV file. I've found that if I comment out the part of my import that saves addresses, it's much faster. Is there some faster way I could do this? I briefly considered putting an index on it but it seems like, since all the fields need to match, an index wouldn't help.

Comment: Hmm. Have you considered using mySQL's native `LOAD DATA INFILE`? I'm not sure how well it can deal with already existing addresses, but I imagine it must be one of the fastest ways

Comment: Also, what does "slow" mean - are you importing 10 addresses, and it takes 20 seconds? Or 100,000, and it takes a minute? ...

Comment: Without seeing the queries/code that actually run on `findOrCreate`, we can't offer that much feedback on how it works. Indexes will absolutely still help in a situation where you're matching all fields.

Comment: Have you looked at the query/queries Doctrine creates? Have you tried analyzing them with `EXPLAIN`? Do any of the seached columns have an index at all?

Comment: I've edited my question to answer the question about what slow means. I've also added the code for `findOrCreate()`.

Comment: Gordon, the answer to all your questions is no. I'll look into those things. Thanks.

Comment: You could also use a profiler like XDebug or Zend_Debugger to make sure it is really the database and not the CSV parsing itself that's causing a slowdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This certainly won't alleviate all of the time spent on tens of thousands of iterations, but why don't you manage your addresses outside of per-iteration DB queries?  The general idea:

1. Get a list of all current addresses (store it in an array)
2. As you iterate, check array membership (checksums [sic]); if it doesn't exist, store the new address in the array and save the address to the database.

Unless I'm misunderstanding the scenario, this way you're only making INSERT queries if you have to, and you don't need to perform any SELECT queries aside from the first one.

Comment: This is probably the best idea yet. I might do this. (I say "might" because I already found a different, easier solution that might be sufficient.)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you investigate loading the CSV files into MySQL using `LOAD DATA INFILE`:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

In order to update existing rows, you have a couple of options. `LOAD DATA INFILE` does not have upsert functionality (insert...on duplicate key update), but it does have a `REPLACE` option, which you could use to update existing rows, but you need to make sure you have an appropriate unique index, and the REPLACE is really just a `DELETE` and `INSERT`, which is slower than an `UPDATE`.

Another option is to load the data from the CSV into a temporary table, then merge that table with the live table using `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDAT`E. Again, make sure you have an appropriate unique index, but in this case you're doing an update instead of a delete so it should be faster.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to the term "upsert". It gave me the search term I needed to find my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your duplicate checking is what is slowing you down.  To find out why, figure out what query Doctrine is creating and run `EXPLAIN` on it.

My guess would be that you will need to create some indexes.  Searching through the entire table can be very slow, but adding an index to zip would allow the query to only do a full search through addresses with that zip code.  The `EXPLAIN` will be able to guide you to other optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing, that improved performance greatly, was to use [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) instead of using `findOrCreate()`.